# Finding and listing consecutive timespans by group and condition using R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe such as

```
ts  id  cnt
2023-06-01 00:00:00 1   2
2023-06-01 00:01:00 1   2
2023-06-01 00:02:00 1   2
2023-06-01 00:03:00 1   3
2023-06-01 00:04:00 1   3
2023-06-01 00:05:00 1   3
2023-06-01 00:06:00 1   2
2023-06-01 00:07:00 1   2
2023-06-01 00:08:00 1   1
2023-06-01 00:09:00 1   1
2023-06-01 00:10:00 1   0
2023-06-01 00:11:00 1   0
2023-06-01 00:12:00 1   0
2023-06-01 00:13:00 1   0
2023-06-01 00:14:00 1   0
2023-06-01 00:15:00 1   0
2023-06-01 00:16:00 1   1
2023-06-01 00:17:00 1   1
....
2023-06-01 00:00:00 2   0
2023-06-01 00:01:00 2   0
2023-06-01 00:02:00 2   0
2023-06-01 00:03:00 2   0
2023-06-01 00:04:00 2   0
2023-06-01 00:05:00 2   0
2023-06-01 00:06:00 2   1
2023-06-01 00:07:00 2   1
2023-06-01 00:08:00 2   1
2023-06-01 00:09:00 2   1
2023-06-01 00:10:00 2   1
...
2023-06-01 00:27:00 4   0
2023-06-01 00:28:00 4   0
2023-06-01 00:29:00 4   0
2023-06-01 00:30:00 4   0
2023-06-01 00:00:00 5   NA
2023-06-01 00:01:00 5   1
2023-06-01 00:02:00 5   1
2023-06-01 00:03:00 5   1
2023-06-01 00:04:00 5   1
2023-06-01 00:05:00 5   0
2023-06-01 00:06:00 5   0
...
```

It may not be ordered. It contains a timestamp for every minute of a day. ts is never NA and id is never NA. cnt can be NA. There are no gaps in the timestamps, but there can be gaps in the id's.

I want to find and list consecutive timespans per group, where a condition is fullfilled. Here if cnt is 0. NA values shall be treated like every other value other than 0. By listing consecutive timespans I am talking about a string of the first occurence of 0 concatenated by e.g. a minus, followed by the last timestamp where cnt is 0.
For example `2023-06-01 00:10:00 - 2023-06-01 00:15:00`

To illustrate the desired result I am looking for, it is:

```
id,date,null_cnt,null_from_to
1,2023-06-01,12,2023-06-01 00:10:00 - 2023-06-01 00:15:00; 2023-06-01 00:20:00 - 2023-06-01 00:25:00
2,2023-06-01,18,2023-06-01 00:00:00 - 2023-06-01 00:05:00; 2023-06-01 00:15:00 - 2023-06-01 00:20:00; 2023-06-01 00:25:00 - 2023-06-01 00:30:00
3,2023-06-01,0,NA
4,2023-06-01,31,2023-06-01 00:00:00 - 2023-06-01 00:30:00
5,2023-06-01,10,2023-06-01 00:05:00 - 2023-06-01 00:10:00; 2023-06-01 00:26:00 - 2023-06-01 00:27:00; 2023-06-01 00:29:00 - 2023-06-01 00:30:00
```

Since I could not find any guidance the last days on how to solve this issue and I am not an expert in R, I wrote a rather complicated nested ifelse structure while looping over an ordered dataframe. It may not cover all possible cases, but so far it does what I am looking for.

**However, I am asking if there is a way more simple solution to achive my desired result?**

```r
df <- data.frame (ts = c('2023-06-01 00:00:00', '2023-06-01 00:01:00',  '2023-06-01 00:02:00',  '2023-06-01 00:03:00',  '2023-06-01 00:04:00',  '2023-06-01 00:05:00',  '2023-06-01 00:06:00',  '2023-06-01 00:07:00',  '2023-06-01 00:08:00',  '2023-06-01 00:09:00',  '2023-06-01 00:10:00',  '2023-06-01 00:11:00',  '2023-06-01 00:12:00',  '2023-06-01 00:13:00',  '2023-06-01 00:14:00',  '2023-06-01 00:15:00',  '2023-06-01 00:16:00',  '2023-06-01 00:17:00',  '2023-06-01 00:18:00',  '2023-06-01 00:19:00',  '2023-06-01 00:20:00',  '2023-06-01 00:21:00',  '2023-06-01 00:22:00',  '2023-06-01 00:23:00',  '2023-06-01 00:24:00',  '2023-06-01 00:25:00',  '2023-06-01 00:26:00',  '2023-06-01 00:27:00',  '2023-06-01 00:28:00',  '2023-06-01 00:29:00',  '2023-06-01 00:30:00',  '2023-06-01 00:00:00',  '2023-06-01 00:01:00',  '2023-06-01 00:02:00',  '2023-06-01 00:03:00',  '2023-06-01 00:04:00',  '2023-06-01 00:05:00',  '2023-06-01 00:06:00',  '2023-06-01 00:07:00',  '2023-06-01 00:08:00',  '2023-06-01 00:09:00',  '2023-06-01 00:10:00',  '2023-06-01 00:11:00',  '2023-06-01 00:12:00',  '2023-06-01 00:13:00',  '2023-06-01 00:14:00',  '2023-06-01 00:15:00',  '2023-06-01 00:16:00',  '2023-06-01 00:17:00',  '2023-06-01 00:18:00',  '2023-06-01 00:19:00',  '2023-06-01 00:20:00',  '2023-06-01 00:21:00',  '2023-06-01 00:22:00',  '2023-06-01 00:23:00',  '2023-06-01 00:24:00',  '2023-06-01 00:25:00',  '2023-06-01 00:26:00',  '2023-06-01 00:27:00',  '2023-06-01 00:28:00',  '2023-06-01 00:29:00',  '2023-06-01 00:30:00',  '2023-06-01 00:00:00',  '2023-06-01 00:01:00',  '2023-06-01 00:02:00',  '2023-06-01 00:03:00',  '2023-06-01 00:04:00',  '2023-06-01 00:05:00',  '2023-06-01 00:06:00',  '2023-06-01 00:07:00',  '2023-06-01 00:08:00',  '2023-06-01 00:09:00',  '2023-06-01 00:10:00',  '2023-06-01 00:11:00',  '2023-06-01 00:12:00',  '2023-06-01 00:13:00',  '2023-06-01 00:14:00',  '2023-06-01 00:15:00',  '2023-06-01 00:16:00',  '2023-06-01 00:17:00',  '2023-06-01 00:18:00',  '2023-06-01 00:19:00',  '2023-06-01 00:20:00',  '2023-06-01 00:21:00',  '2023-06-01 00:22:00',  '2023-06-01 00:23:00',  '2023-06-01 00:24:00',  '2023-06-01 00:25:00',  '2023-06-01 00:26:00',  '2023-06-01 00:27:00',  '2023-06-01 00:28:00',  '2023-06-01 00:29:00',  '2023-06-01 00:30:00',  '2023-06-01 00:00:00',  '2023-06-01 00:01:00',  '2023-06-01 00:02:00',  '2023-06-01 00:03:00',  '2023-06-01 00:04:00',  '2023-06-01 00:05:00',  '2023-06-01 00:06:00',  '2023-06-01 00:07:00',  '2023-06-01 00:08:00',  '2023-06-01 00:09:00',  '2023-06-01 00:10:00',  '2023-06-01 00:11:00',  '2023-06-01 00:12:00',  '2023-06-01 00:13:00',  '2023-06-01 00:14:00',  '2023-06-01 00:15:00',  '2023-06-01 00:16:00',  '2023-06-01 00:17:00',  '2023-06-01 00:18:00',  '2023-06-01 00:19:00',  '2023-06-01 00:20:00',  '2023-06-01 00:21:00',  '2023-06-01 00:22:00',  '2023-06-01 00:23:00',  '2023-06-01 00:24:00',  '2023-06-01 00:25:00',  '2023-06-01 00:26:00',  '2023-06-01 00:27:00',  '2023-06-01 00:28:00',  '2023-06-01 00:29:00',  '2023-06-01 00:30:00',  '2023-06-01 00:00:00',  '2023-06-01 00:01:00',  '2023-06-01 00:02:00',  '2023-06-01 00:03:00',  '2023-06-01 00:04:00',  '2023-06-01 00:05:00',  '2023-06-01 00:06:00',  '2023-06-01 00:07:00',  '2023-06-01 00:08:00',  '2023-06-01 00:09:00',  '2023-06-01 00:10:00',  '2023-06-01 00:11:00',  '2023-06-01 00:12:00',  '2023-06-01 00:13:00',  '2023-06-01 00:14:00',  '2023-06-01 00:15:00',  '2023-06-01 00:16:00',  '2023-06-01 00:17:00',  '2023-06-01 00:18:00',  '2023-06-01 00:19:00',  '2023-06-01 00:20:00',  '2023-06-01 00:21:00',  '2023-06-01 00:22:00',  '2023-06-01 00:23:00',  '2023-06-01 00:24:00',  '2023-06-01 00:25:00',  '2023-06-01 00:26:00',  '2023-06-01 00:27:00',  '2023-06-01 00:28:00',  '2023-06-01 00:29:00',  '2023-06-01 00:30:00'),
                  id = c(1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5),
                  cnt = c(2,    2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  2,  2,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3,  3,  1,  1,  2,  5,  2,  5,  4,  4,  1,  2,  2,  3,  5,  4,  1,  1,  2,  5,  1,  5,  1,  3,  3,  4,  1,  3,  4,  1,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  NA, 1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0,  0,  NA, 0,  0)
)

res <- data.frame(id=integer(), date=character(), null_cnt=integer(), null_from_to=character())
df <- df[order(df$id,df$ts),]
first <- strptime('9999-01-01 00:00:01', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
cons <- c()
nullcnt <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  tstamp <- format(strptime(df$ts[i], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  if(i == nrow(df)){ # if end of df
    if(df$cnt[i]==0){
      nullcnt <- nullcnt + 1
      last <- tstamp
      if(first>tstamp){
        first <- tstamp
      }
    }
    if(first!=strptime('9999-01-01 00:00:01', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")){
      cons <- append(cons, paste0(first," - ",last))
    }
    res[nrow(res) + 1,] <- c(df$id[i], as.character(as.Date(df$ts[i])), nullcnt, paste(cons, collapse = "; "))
  }else if(df$id[i] != df$id[i+1]){ # if end of group
    if(!is.na(df$cnt[i])&df$cnt[i]==0){
      nullcnt <- nullcnt + 1
      last <- tstamp
    }
    if(first!=strptime('9999-01-01 00:00:01', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")){
      cons <- append(cons, paste0(first," - ",last))
    }
    res[nrow(res) + 1,] <- c(df$id[i], as.character(as.Date(df$ts[i])), nullcnt, paste(cons, collapse = "; "))
    cons <- c()
    first <- strptime('9999-01-01 00:00:01', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    nullcnt <- 0
  }else{
    if(is.na(df$cnt[i]) | df$cnt[i]!=0){
      first <- strptime('9999-01-01 00:00:01', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    }else if(df$cnt[i]==0){
      nullcnt <- nullcnt + 1
      if(first>tstamp){
        first <- tstamp
      }
      if(first<tstamp){
        last <- tstamp
        if(is.na(df$cnt[i+1]) | df$cnt[i+1]!=0){
          if(first!=strptime('9999-01-01 00:00:01', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")){
            cons <- append(cons, paste0(first," - ",last))
          }
          first <- strptime('9999-01-01 00:00:01', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        }
      }
    }    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another `tidyverse` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(rleid = with(rle(cnt == 0 & !is.na(cnt)), rep(cumsum(values) * values, lengths))) %>%
 filter(rleid != 0) %>%
 group_by(id, rleid) %>%
 summarise(from = first(ts),
           to = last(ts),
           null_count = n()) %>%
 ungroup()

     id rleid from                to                  null_count
  <dbl> <int> <chr>               <chr>                    <int>
1     1     1 2023-06-01 00:10:00 2023-06-01 00:15:00          6
2     1     2 2023-06-01 00:20:00 2023-06-01 00:25:00          6
3     2     1 2023-06-01 00:00:00 2023-06-01 00:05:00          6
4     2     2 2023-06-01 00:15:00 2023-06-01 00:20:00          6
5     2     3 2023-06-01 00:25:00 2023-06-01 00:30:00          6
6     4     1 2023-06-01 00:00:00 2023-06-01 00:30:00         31
7     5     1 2023-06-01 00:05:00 2023-06-01 00:10:00          6
8     5     2 2023-06-01 00:26:00 2023-06-01 00:27:00          2
9     5     3 2023-06-01 00:29:00 2023-06-01 00:30:00          2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses `tidyverse` tools.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  mutate(ts = as_datetime(ts)) |> 
  arrange(id, ts) |> 
  filter(cnt == 0) |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(previous_ts = lag(ts),
         consecutive = difftime(ts, previous_ts) == 1 | is.na(previous_ts),
         cons_id = cumsum(!consecutive)) |> 
  group_by(id, cons_id) |>
  mutate(null_count = n()) |> 
  filter(ts == min(ts) | ts == max(ts)) |> 
  select(-previous_ts, -consecutive, -cnt) |> 
  mutate(cons_group_id = consecutive_id(ts)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(from_to = factor(cons_group_id, labels = c("from", "to"))) |> 
  select(-cons_group_id) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = from_to,
              values_from = ts) |> 
  filter(null_count > 1)
#> # A tibble: 9 × 5
#>      id cons_id null_count from                to                 
#>   <dbl>   <int>      <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1     1       0          6 2023-06-01 00:10:00 2023-06-01 00:15:00
#> 2     1       1          6 2023-06-01 00:20:00 2023-06-01 00:25:00
#> 3     2       0          6 2023-06-01 00:00:00 2023-06-01 00:05:00
#> 4     2       1          6 2023-06-01 00:15:00 2023-06-01 00:20:00
#> 5     2       2          6 2023-06-01 00:25:00 2023-06-01 00:30:00
#> 6     4       0         31 2023-06-01 00:00:00 2023-06-01 00:30:00
#> 7     5       0          6 2023-06-01 00:05:00 2023-06-01 00:10:00
#> 8     5       1          2 2023-06-01 00:26:00 2023-06-01 00:27:00
#> 9     5       2          2 2023-06-01 00:29:00 2023-06-01 00:30:00
```

Answer (score 1):

- First `arrange` by *id* and *ts* to make sure the time/dates are in the right order
- Then construct *null_cnt* and *null_from_to*
- `filter` for zero *cnts*
- Finally compact the lines with `nest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(id, ts) %>% 
  group_by(id, grp = consecutive_id(cnt)) %>% 
  reframe(cnt, 
          date = sub(" .*", "", ts[1]), 
          null_cnt = n(), 
          null_from_to = paste(ts[1], "-", ts[n()])) %>% 
  filter(cnt == 0) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  select(-c(grp, cnt)) %>% 
  nest(null_from_to = null_from_to) %>% 
  data.frame()
  id       date null_cnt
1  1 2023-06-01        6
2  2 2023-06-01        6
3  4 2023-06-01       31
4  5 2023-06-01        6
5  5 2023-06-01        2
                                                                                                                     null_from_to
1                                            2023-06-01 00:10:00 - 2023-06-01 00:15:00, 2023-06-01 00:20:00 - 2023-06-01 00:25:00
2 2023-06-01 00:00:00 - 2023-06-01 00:05:00, 2023-06-01 00:15:00 - 2023-06-01 00:20:00, 2023-06-01 00:25:00 - 2023-06-01 00:30:00
3                                                                                       2023-06-01 00:00:00 - 2023-06-01 00:30:00
4                                                                                       2023-06-01 00:05:00 - 2023-06-01 00:10:00
5                                            2023-06-01 00:26:00 - 2023-06-01 00:27:00, 2023-06-01 00:29:00 - 2023-06-01 00:30:00
```